# Reachability and signal strength

Tags: ios, wifi, reachability, signal-strength

I am using Apple's Reachability class, and have written a simple test app to just surface the events it picks up.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    [self initializeNetworkReachability];
    ...
}

#pragma mark - Network Reachability/Connection methods

- (void)initializeNetworkReachability {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkConnection:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
    internetAvailable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetAvailable startNotifier];
    [self checkConnection:nil];
}

- (void)checkConnection:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetAvailable currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (internetStatus) {
        case NotReachable:
            _isConnectedToInternet = NO;
            break;
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
            _isConnectedToInternet = YES;
            break;
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
            _isConnectedToInternet = YES;
            break;
        default:
            _isConnectedToInternet = NO;
            break;
    }

    [self connectionAchieved:_isConnectedToInternet];
}

- (void)connectionAchieved:(BOOL)achieved {
    _isConnectedToInternet = achieved;
}
```

All pretty plain vanilla... but herein lies the rub.  If I go to a place where I know my connectivity is completely useless (a place on the street just outside my office building), I do not get a network reachability changed notification.  However, if I open Safari and try browsing a website, it is impossible to reach and just hangs trying to load the page.

I went as far as wandering down the street watching my WiFi indicator and cellular signal strength, which changed but I never got a signal from the reachability stuff.

Finally, I went into a store, walked to the very back, and watched WiFi switch to cellular 1x (I am on an iPhone 5), and finally got a reachability change (no network available).  The entire time the network was completely unusable.

Am I doing something wrong?  Misinterpreting/Misunderstanding the usage of Reachability?  Or, if not, how in the world do people handle these conditions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that you are describing is exactly how I would expect the Reachability API to behave.  Its basically a way to simply know if your device is connected over WiFi, cellular or has no connection at all.  It gives no indication of the signal strength or the **quality** of the network connection.

Comment: That seems like the case.  But what is the "best practice" for handling those in-between conditions where Reachability says you are connected but the connection is essentially useless?  A client-side time-out, or is there some better way?

Comment: I don't know if there is anything like a 'best practice' for this, but I have used client side timeouts in the past.

Comment: Thank Jonathan.  I appreciate the input.